# CSS/JS select devices that are not landscape and min-width of 980px

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, media, tablet

I have a small problem I'm trying to solve.  On my drupal website, I have written a script that allows for shadowboxes to open up youtube links only for a min-width of 980px.  This works fine and dandy, but my issue comes in with landscape orientated tablets.  This rule was to prevent shadowbox from opening on mobile platforms.  So I would like to modify my code to prevent any landscape devices as well as all devices under 980px.  Can I get some help with the logic behind this?  I tried using NOT (orientation:landscape), but NOT reverses the logic on the whole line I believe.

```
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {

  $(document).ready(function () {
    var mq = window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 980px)" );
    if (mq.matches) {
      Shadowbox.init();
    }
  });

})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I realized what I was doing wrong right after posting.  I'll leave it up in case it helps anyone else.  I had forgotten that it needs a comma in between to separate the queries.

```
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {

  $(document).ready(function () {
    var mq = window.matchMedia( "(not (orientation:landscape),(min-width: 980px)" );
    if (mq.matches) {
      Shadowbox.init();
    }
  });

})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```